# ModelBuilder model only works in edit window?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I have a model that iterates through a single field (such as Name) and selects out each name in that field and ultimately creates a KML layer as the last output of each name in the field by using an in line varible (For Example %Value%). The goal is to have a tool that one can input any shapefile, choose their desired field of choice, and have the tool iterate and create KMLs of each individual value in that chosen field. The issue is right now the tool works fine when I open it in the Edit window and add the data there in the ModelBuilder window but I was hoping to be able to run it like a traditional tool in ArcMap by clicking open and adding the data there. I have set every output from each tool in the model as a parameter so I can control where the temporary files are being stored at every step.

How can I get a successful model that runs in the edit window but not from the open window?

Comment: What does your model look like, preferably simplified, but still showing your issue?

Comment: Is your model running from the toolbox and failing, or are you trying to get it into the toolbox?

Comment: When Im in Arc Catalog I right click on the tool for a window to pop up with a few options to Open (This is where I am trying to get the model to work properly), Batch, Edit (Model works in this Edit mode perfectly), Debug, Copy, Delete, and so on. I don't know why you need to see the model. All you need to know is that it works fine in the edit window but not when I click open and run it more like a traditional tool.

Answer (score 1):

I believe all you need to do is right click on the fields/values you want users to enter while in Edit View and choose Model Parameter. That should put a large "P" near the model shape. The parameters should then appear in the model's Open View as input boxes.

BTW, I prefer to run models in Edit View if I am the only one using them because I can see tool names and preconditions, and I can watch what stage it is running at.